# systemd: disable useless tmpfs

Tags: linux, systemd, overlay, tmpfs

Context: embedded system, read-only MMC with `tmpfs` overlay. Everything gets written to RAM & disappears on reboot.

`systemd` insists on creating numerous `tmpfs` mounts (at least `/run` `/run/lock` `/run/shm` and `/tmp` from the top of my head, perhaps others), which are totally useless since the whole read-only filesystem is already overlaid by a `tmpfs`.

Problem: this is quite a constrained embedded system and every byte of RAM counts. I'd like to avoid the overhead of managing multiple `tmpfs` in different locations, and just put everything in the main `tmpfs` overlay.

Unfortunately so far I've only managed to disable `/tmp` (`systemctl mask systemd-tmpfiles*`) but it does nothing for the `/run` hierarchy.

Any idea where those settings are hidden?

Comment: If every byte of RAM counts, wouldn't replacing the whole `systemd` with a smaller init be the first course of action? You'd free up several _megabytes_ compared to a tmpfs mount costing a few kB.

Comment: You're obviously right, and this is planned. Unfortunately there are ramifications (mainly hotplug) that I don't have time to handle yet. This will have to wait, in the meantime I'm trying to make do...

Comment: Just use devuan Linux (https://www.devuan.org/) as a base / starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

**Required:**

`/sys/fs/cgroup` cannot be disabled, as systemd's standard functionality relies on cgroups.

`/dev` cannot and *should not* be disabled, as it's not a regular tmpfs – it's a devtmpfs, where the kernel automatically creates nodes for hotplugged devices. (This works even without udev.)

**Difficult:**

`/run` cannot be disabled; you can **patch it out** from the table in systemd's `src/core/mount-setup.c`, but do so only as long as the location still provides the same tmpfs-like properties.

`/run/shm` also cannot be disabled, because it is required by glibc to implement POSIX shared memory. Again, you can patch it out of `src/core/mount-setup.c`, as long as the location remains *on* a tmpfs. Keep in mind that this path is a custom distribution patch – traditionally this filesystem would be at `/dev/shm`.

**Optional:**

`/dev/mqueue`, `/dev/hugepages` are mounted according to their `.mount` unit files, which can be deleted.

`/run/lock` isn't actually a tmpfs by default. If you see something mounted at that location, it must be your distribution's custom addition and very likely can be disabled by removing the `run-lock.mount` unit.

`/tmp` is optional, and is mounted according to the `tmp.mount` unit. You can remove that unit file.

---

I would be very surprised if a tmpfs mount cost more than a memory page.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I feared : some of it is hardcoded. That "we know better than you" attitude from the systemd team is tiring me.
Well I'm not recompiling systemd just for this, so I'll just get rid of it all as you suggested when I have some time to do it.